# Check instance of T and call corresponding constructor conditionally

Tags: java, oop, object

I am using this code below but let me first explain what I want to achieve. I have 3 classes, `Publisher`, `Consumer`, and `Broker`. I want to create a static method that accepts arguments from CLI and returns a list of each class depending on what I specify. The example below is fully functional but only works for the `Publisher` class. My question is, how can I modify the below code to accept multiple classes and return `List< T >` instead of `List< Publisher >`. I have tried using generics but this way, I cannot call the constructor to create a new Object. Do not worry about the String splits, this has nothing to do with the problem, the main focus is inside the while loop where I instantiate an Object. My goal is to use this class this way

`ArgParser.< Publisher >fetchEntitiesFromCommandLine(args)`

`ArgParser.< Broker > fetchEntitiesFromCommandLine(args)`

`ArgParser.< Consumer > fetchEntitiesFromCommandLine(args)`

Thanks in advance!

```
public class ArgParser {
    public static List<Publisher> fetchPublishersFromCommandLine(String[] args) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        List<Publisher> publishers = new ArrayList<>();
        int position = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
            if (args[i].equals("-p")) {
                position = i;
            }
        }
        if (position == -1)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        try {
            while (args[++position] != null) {
                String[] data = args[position].split(":");
                Publisher publisher = new Publisher(data[0], Integer.parseInt(data[1]));
                publishers.add(publisher);
            }
            // This line never executes, however compiler warned me.
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
        } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException err) {
            return publishers;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how do you specify which class to instantiate in args? do they have a common super class or interface?

Comment: @SharonBenAsher no they do not have anything in common, maybe they should though...

Answer (score 0):

For a a list to contain multiple types, they should have a common super class or interface (if you don't want to revert to `List<Object>`).
Regarding the instantiation of a new instance of generic type `T`: You must obtain the concrete class of the instance. If I understand correctly, the concrete type can be determined from the runtime args. There are two options here

1. once you parsed the args and determined the concrete type, use switch-case and inquire on each possible value. The code below assumes an interface `Person` that all possible concrete types implement:

   ```
   List<? extends Person> returnList = new ArrayList<>();
   String personType = determinePersonTypeFromArgs(args);
   Person person = null;
   switch (personType) {
       case "publisher" :
           person = new Publisher(...);
       case "bromer" :
           person = new Broker(...);
       case "consumer" :
           person = new Consumer(...);
   }
   if (person != null) returnList.add(person);
   return returnList;
   ```

   This a relatively simple solution. However, introducing a new type of `Person` requires code change and there are more chances of errors from typos and such .
2. Use reflection to instantiate a concrete `Person`. In this case, the String must contain the exact full class name (including package) and you must get the constructor according to arg types. In short - more complicated boilerplate code. However, it is more extensible and resilient.